# How do I easily get the list of packages I removed with `autoremove` switch

Tags: apt, package-management

I am on ubuntu MATE 16.04. After the usual `dist-upgrade` i made the mistake to do `autoremove`. From `/var/log/apt/history.log` i know which all packages i removed by mistake. This was a mistake because now many functionalities are not working. Computer is still working. I have the package manager, terminal, chrome, etc. But some other features like additional drivers, ros rviz, firefox, etc. don't work. SO i am reluctant to backup and remove ubuntu and again install it from scratch.  I need to reinstall the packages `autoremove` automatically removed. Is there an easy way to reinstall those packages. It is difficult to skim through all the package names and install them. Is there a more automated way or easier tool to do this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once wrote a ruby script for analyzing apt-log history. You can find the script [here on github](https://github.com/AnwarShah/apt-log-analyzer/blob/master/apt-log-analyzer.rb).

You need ruby to execute the script. It's easy

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

Once done, download the script, save whatever name you like. If you save it as `apt-log-analyzer.rb` file, execute it with this command

```
ruby ./apt-log-analyzer.rb
```

It will show you all the package names. Then you can copy the package names.

Using a pipe like `ruby ./apt-log-analyzer.rb | cut -d ' ' -f 1` should make the copying thing easier.

Hope it will help some.